# .htaccess Redirect subdomain to domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a subdomain http://sub.domain.com

I want all links from this subdomain be redirected to a target domain
with www, nonwww and also redirect the path.

REDIRECT:

www = http://www.sub.domain.com

nonWww = http://sub.domain.com

path = http://sub.domain.com/something/anything

to TARGET:

http://www.domain.com/sub/zero

What is the .htaccess for this?

What would be the change if i don't want to transport the path to the new target,
so have a static target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# target with original URI being carried over
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

And for 2nd part:

```
# static target
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/sub/zero [NE,R=301,L]
```