# redirect subdomain url to main domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've a problem i cant figure out. People access this url:
http://www.sub.domain.net/action
but they need to be redirect to
https://www.domain.net/action/action2

I tried doing this with this line in .htaccess:
Redirect http://www.sub.domain.net/action https://www.domain.net/action/action2

But it's not working.
I only need this specific url to be redirected, not the entire www.sub.domain.net. Any advice?

Comment: Do you always want `action2/` to be added while redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This and check if it works for you.Change Links in the code.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

    # target with original URI being carried over
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

And for 2nd part:

```
# static target
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/sub/zero [NE,R=301,L]
```

Why you didn't use jquery,javascript or php to redirect `onload` from one page to another?

This answer is extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181355/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-domain/21181671#21181671).