# Subdomain wildcard redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, dns, subdomain, cpanel

I'm running a minor WordPress (multisite/network) site, on a server using cPanel. The site used to have a lot of subdomains like:

- `shop.example.com`
- `cars.example.com`
- `music.example.com`
- and so on...

**The problem:**
Most of the subdomains are no longer available (neither in the DNS nor anywhere else) - so when you try to reach shop.example.com it just hits a 404.

**So my question is:**
How do I get all subdomains to redirect to `example.com`?

**What have i done/tried already:**

- DNS a `*.example.com` record pointing to the correct IP
- DNS CNAME `*.example.com` record pointing to `example.com`
- Doing this forced it onto the server, so its no longer just a 404, but the server doesn't recognize `shop.example.com`
- Tried messing with subdomains/domain in cPanel (creating a `*.example.com`), and a couple of other different things
- Tried different redirects in cPanel

So what am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure I need to do a combination of setting up a wildcard DNS record, and doing something in CPanel :P - but I just can't figure out exactly what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post

> Doing this forced it onto the server, so its no longer just a 404, but
>   the server doesn't recognize `shop.example.com`

You then need to do a 301 Redirect from `shop.example.com` to wherever you want to go, you can do this is in the CPanel.  You will have to do this for each subdomain that that once existed therefore handling any requests that might come.

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to use the wildcard like you can for the IP.  Each subdomain is a separate website as far as the webserver software, such as Apache, is concerned.  So when you do a redirect you are answering the webserver software question, "OK, I got a HTTP GET request for `shop.example.com`, what files do I serve up? "

See this [section in the CPanel docs](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/subdomains/#enable-or-disable-subdomain-redirection) for more information on redirecting.

Comment: So i have to go into subdomains, and create each and every subdomain and force a redirect from it? That was one of my worst fears :D

Comment: Bonus question - if have shop.example.com/something can i get it to redirect regardless of the subfolder? i want i want shop.example.com/[anything] to redirect to example.com

Comment: Yes, I believe you could through .htaccess and the use of regex, when I searched for that, there is a chance I am wrong in that there may be a htacess regex that also gets you the subdomain work you need, but I have no earthly idea how to write it - not a regex expert, but you can start here, maybe someone else will chime in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181355/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-domain